# How to run java class command line?

Tags: java, cmd, classpath, scjp

I have the following test question:

> Given:
>
> ```
> 1. package com.company.application;
> 2.
> 3. public class MainClass {
> 4. public static void main(String[] args) {}
> 5. }
> ```
>
> And `MainClass` exists in the /apps/com/company/application directory. Assume the CLASSPATH
>   environment variable is set to "." (current directory).Which two java commands entered at the command
>   line will run `MainClass`? (Choose two.)
>
> A. java MainClass if run from the /apps directory
>       B. java com.company.application.MainClass if run from the /apps directory
>       C. java -classpath /apps com.company.application.MainClass if run from any directory
>       D. java -classpath . MainClass if run from the /apps/com/company/application directory
>       E. java -classpath /apps/com/company/application:. MainClass if run from the /apps directory
>       F. java com.company.application.MainClass if run from the /apps/com/company/application directory

I think the correct are D and E but the are B and C and I am wondering why?

Comment: [Because.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should execute a class using its full name. The full name of a class consists of:

```
<package location> + <simple name of class>
```

With this in mind, `MainClass` full name is `com.company.application.MainClass`.

Java can locate this class from the directory that contains the top directory in the package tree. From the example, the root directory is `/apps`:

```
apps <-- root
+ com <-- here the package starts
  + company
    + application
      - MainClass.class
```

So this root directory should be in the classpath in order that Java program (the JVM) can access to the compiled classes and the entry point of the app.

---

From the question:

> Assume the CLASSPATH environment variable is set to "." (current directory).

Option B states:

> B. `java com.company.application.MainClass` **if run from the /apps directory**

Since you're in `/apps` directory and the current directory is the CLASSPATH, so Java can locate the designated class to execute.

Option C states:

> C. `java -classpath /apps com.company.application.MainClass` **if run from any directory**

In this case, you're setting `/apps` as CLASSPATH, so Java can locate the designated class to execute.

All the other options fails to accomplish the explanation above.

Comment: Save this question/answer somewhere and use it to close duplicates. (Add a link to the launcher.)

Comment: @Luiggi but what about E? If the current dir is /app and on the classpath we have ., then why MainClass can not be found?

Comment: @Xelian because the name of the class is `com.company.application.MainClass`. The JVM will look into com/company/application and check for a MainClass.class file to execute (that's the meaning of packages). If you just use `java -cp /apps MainClass` the JVM will look for MainClass.class file in /apps folder, which doesn't exist and will fail. I highly recommend you to test every case manually to check how the java program behaves.

Comment: Thanks @Luiggi I reread [at]Sotirios link but I still have problems with command line compiling.

Comment: Set the JRE path in your PATH system environment variable. Then you will be able to execute javac and java programs. With this, create an apps folder in a base path, for example if Windows, then C:\base\apps if unix-linux then /home/base/apps. After doing this, create the folder structure and the java class as the exercise recommends, then go to the base path (explained before), compile the file using javac in command line, then try to execute it using java in command line. This exercise will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Because MainClass is part of the package com.company.application, and must be ran as such (com.company.application.MainClass). You cannot run MainClass by itself, or just using .MainClass.
To check yourself, try running each option in a command line!

Answer (score 0):

A. java MainClass if run from the /apps directory  [java wont find the class from its classpath]

B. java com.company.application.MainClass if run from the /apps directory [ yes ]

C. java -classpath /apps com.company.application.MainClass if run from any directory [yes]

D. java -classpath . MainClass if run from the /apps/com/company/application directory [No the package structure should be followed during execution]

E. java -classpath /apps/com/company/application:. MainClass if run from the /apps directory  [yes]

F. java com.company.application.MainClass if run from the /apps/com/company/application directory[no need to follow structure]